# How can I read current Google Analytics API limits or used quota

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, gae-quotas, google-console-developer

We have a widget which [filters analytics referrer spam](https://www.adwordsrobot.com/en/tools/ga-referrer-spam-killer) in Google Analytics by adding 30+ filters to each property-view.

Google Analytics API has a limit of 500 write operation per day, which sucks, because our widget is used a lot and we need around 35 writes per property-view.

I'm looking for a way to read the current API limit so I can notify users when the limit is reached, because right now I'm showing a message when I get an error message from Google - after the request. Which is annoying.

Google Dev. Console contains the usage per API call and what would be enough for me to know when we reached the limit.

[image: Used quote per call]

**My question**: Is there an API which can read out this data for the past 24 hours?

Comment: good question as I would like to be able to have a service which queries how many daily API calls I have made (because right now I am hovering just under the 50,000/day limit).